# heroku websockets support:-

Tags: heroku, websocket

What should I do?

```
heroku labs:enable websockets
```

For which heroku says:- `WARNING: This feature is experimental and may change or be removed without notice.`

Or use:-

```
io.configure(function () { 
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
  io.set("polling duration", 10); 
});
```

Keeping stability in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku Labs:- is used for beta versions of heroku. Its unstable at the moment.

```
io.configure(function () { 
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
  io.set("polling duration", 10); 
});
```

The above is stable.